# Only escape "special" URI characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

In JavaScript there are the two methods `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()`. The former method only replaces special characters such as spaces, umlauts, accent marks, etc. The latter also replaces the reserved symbols `, / ? : @ & = + $` and `#`. But is there a method that replaces **only** these few reserved symbols and leaves special characters and umlauts intact?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: @D.Pardal For my vue router. For a few routes, it is a requirement to display a readable title in the URL, just like "mypage.com/viewers/123-This is my first article". But if the user adds some reserved characters to the page title, like a hashtag or slash, it breaks the vue router right now. That's why I want to escape only those characters where it is unavoidable. So the title "mypage.com/viewers/567-A page about the uppercase/lowercase umlauts ä ö and ü" should still look appropriate and only replace the slash.

Comment: Have you tried with `encodeURIComponent()`? Browsers show some characters unescaped in the address bar.

Comment: @D.Pardal Nope, it at least replaces spaces with a %20.

Comment: But when I type `%20` in the address bar, the browser shows a space.

Comment: @D.Pardal But when I call my Vue.js router method `this.$router.push(\`Roles/${d.id}-${encodeURIComponent(d.name)}\`);`, the script replaces and space character with a %20 rigorously.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own set of characters to replace, you could always do it yourself. It's just string replacement:

```js
const forbiddenChars = ",/?:@&=+$#"
  .split('')
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = encodeURIComponent(curr);
    return acc;
  }, {});

const replaceIn =
  (input) =>
    input.split('').map(char => forbiddenChars[char] || char).join('');

const myString = "hello / there, you";

console.log(replaceIn(myString));
```

Sorry about the poor performance of splitting the string and mapping over each char, you should probably not do that..